# Get Server and Database Name in SSIS Event Handler Task

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a question regarding ssis packages. I have an ssis package with OnError, OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute. In these event handlers SQL task that perform different task and update different tables. My question is this: there are some system variables that I make use of like the SourceName and SourceDescriptin (which is the current sql task's name and description). I notice there isn't any variables for the connection (Server name, Database name) of the "Source" i.e step. Is there any way to get the database name and server name that Source/Step used? Any help will be much appreciated, thanking you in advance.

Comment: Which version are you using? 2012? . Just want to konw whether you have parameters available.

Comment: To build ssis packages we use visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think, we will have a system variable carrying the Server name and Db name. In an SSIS package, any number of connections can be created in the connection manager. So making them all available in a system variable will be not possible. I think such a thing need to be managed by developer itself. May be these steps will hep you.

```
1. Add a parameter (1 parameter per Server).
This parameter will be available through out the package.
2. When the package is running , if required give value to the parameter from SSIS catalog (through SSIS SPs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How does one use the ssis catalog to achieve this?...I am a baby when it comes to ssis packages. If you have any links with simple examples that will be much appreciated. I am currently looking into it as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the server name, you can use the system variable called MachineName. It will give you the name of the machine the package is running on. As for the DB, you will have to capture it using a Execute SQL Task and store it within a variable of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but cannot use machinename as all of our ssis packages are stored and processed on on server e.g Server1 but the ssis tasks in the package reference other servers and other databases.